# How to get a value from a nested Struct in Golang

Tags: go, struct, unmarshalling

Very new to statically typed languages, so I have this complex struct I'm Unmarshalling

```
type MyStruc1 struct {
    Property1 uint16 `json:property1`
    Property2 struct {
        Sub2Property1 string `json:sub2property1`
        Sub2Property2 uint16 `json:sub2property2`
        Sub2Property3 struct {
            SubSub2Property1 string `json:subsub2property1`
            SubSub2Property2 string `json:subsub2property1`
        } `json:sub2property3`
    } `json:property2`
    Property3 struct {
        Sub3Property1 string `json:sub3property1`
        Sub3Property2 uint16 `json:sub3property2`
        Sub3Property3 struct {
            SubSub3Property1 string `json:subsub3property1`
            SubSub3Property2 string `json:subsub3property1`
        } `json:sub3peroperty3`
    } `json:property3`
    Property4 string `json:property4`
}
```

How do i write a function or struct method to accept any one of these arrays and return the value from MyStruct1? Is this possible?

```
strArray1 := []string{"Property2", "Sub2Property3", "SubSub2Property1"}

strArray2 := []string{"Property3", "Sub3Property1"}

strArray3 := []string{"Property4"}

strArray4 := []string{"Property1"}
```

Thank you ahead of time with any replies

Comment: You are trying to fight against the type system. Don't do that. You'll shout your own foot. Redesign.

Comment: Would be the best way to do this? I'm Unmarshalling the json and i need to extract the value by a string which i'm spitting (e.g. `Property2.Sub2Property3.SubSub2Property1`). So there's no good way to do this?

Comment: Unsure if I understand the problem but take a look at github.com/nytlabs/gojsonexplode . Would this fit your purpose? The package has a few rough edges/errors but I do have patches for them.

Comment: Thank for your reply, I ended up going with a package called jsonq here: https://github.com/jmoiron/jsonq. Works pretty well for what I need

Answer (score 0):

You can with *reflect*

```
func FieldBySlice(strct interface{}, fields []string) interface{} {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(strct)
    for _, field := range fields {
        val = val.FieldByName(field)
    }
    return val.Interface()
}
```

This code works, but you will use it only if very much necessary. It's ugly and not recommended. Try to think different, Go is not scripting, dynamic  language